# How to pass a function as a parameter in Kotlin and print the returning value?

Tags: kotlin

I have this function:

```
fun uppercase(s: String) = s.uppercase()
```

And another function that can takes as a parameter a function as the one above:

```
fun print(uppercase: (s: String) -> String) {
    print(uppercase("Ana"))
}
```

And in main I call:

```
print {
    uppercase("Ana")
}
```

Why should I pass to the uppercase function the name twice? If I remove the argument in print function (<strike>"Ana"</strike>), I get an error. How to pass the String argument only once?

If I use:

```
print(uppercase) //I get StackOverflowError.
```

My goal is to pass a function that takes an argument of type String and returns the uppercase version and the print function and print the result. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write it as

```
print(::uppercase)
```

Comment: Oh, my Goodness. It really worked for me. I will accept the answer as soon as I can. I spent 2hours to finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
  // regular function definition
fun printMe(s:String): Unit{
    println(s)
}
   // higher-order function definition
fun higherfunc( str : String, myfunc: (String) -> Unit){
   // invoke regular function using local name
    myfunc(str)
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // invoke higher-order function
    higherfunc("Like this",::printMe)
}
```